# import video strip VSE into the 3d image plane

Tags: texturing, video-sequence-editor

Can i import a strip from VSE editor and add it in an image plane as a texture?

Comment: I don't think so. You have to export that strip, to png or a movie file. And then you can add it to an image plane. Then you can add a material to your plane and add an image texture/movie texture

Comment: thank you. what a pity, with some extra blender would be the perfect program for animatic

Answer (score 3):

Elements from the VSE or from the Compositor cannot be used as textures on the 3D environment directly.

You would need to export them as Video or Image Sequences and then re-import them to be used as textures on planes (or other geometry).